# Running Emulator on Github Hosted Windows Runner

Tags: github-actions, appium

I am running an emulator after I created an avd with
`-k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"`
on Github Windows(latest) runner
Now when I am running the emulator, its giving me this error:
ERROR | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Now I have checked the extras in Android SDK, there is no Intel Folder. How can I solve this problem.

Context: I am trying to run my Appium+JAVA+TestNG suite on Github Hosted Runner using Github Actions.

I tried to look for an intel folder to install Haxm but i couldnt find it.
Tried Creating an amd system image. When I ran the emulator. It said cant run amd emulator on x86.

Comment: Nested virtualization might not be enabled on GitHub hosted runner machines for any emulator to execute. You can use a self-hosted runner machine instead, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/choosing-the-runner-for-a-job#choosing-self-hosted-runners